# Using Jquery autocomplete, search for entry at beginning of term with external source

Tags: php, jquery, json, autocomplete

My problem is that I want to search for an entry in a database using the starting with the beginning and not middle or end. I saw other StackOverflow answers but those dealt with Jquery's autocomplete taking an array as the source parameter.

Let's assume I have a textbook with the id = school:

```
<input type="text" id="school">
```

In my sample database table I have the following schools:

- Donald Trump Elementary School
- Barack Obama Middle School
- Franklin Delano Roosevelt High School
- Theodore Roosevelt Technical Academy
- John Adams Middle School
- Andrew Jackson Middle School
- Andrew Johnson Day Care
- Bill Clinton Prison Education Program
- Abraham Lincoln Academy of Fine Arts

If I just type an 'A' what is returned is basically anything string with an A in it.

What I want returned are:

- Andrew Jackson Middle School
- Andrew Johnson Day Care
- Abraham Lincoln Academy of Fine Arts

---

```
 $('#school').each(function (i, el) {
     var that = $(el);
     that.autocomplete({
         source: "src/php/extraction.php"
         , minLength: 2
         , select: function (event, ui) {
         info = ui.item.label;                      
         $.ajax({
                url: 'foobar.php'
                , type: 'POST', 
                data: {
                    term : info }
                , success: function (data) {
                    // do stuff }
                });
            } // end of select function
        });
    });
```

In my foobar.php to which the autocomplete sends to, I have the following code:

```
if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
$return_arr = array();
try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT School_Name FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE School_Name LIKE :term');
    $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $return_arr[] = ucwords(strtolower($row['School_Name']));
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: '.$e->getMessage();
}

/* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a right SQL Query:

```
$stmt->execute(array('term' => $_GET['term'].'%'));
```

If you want only the results starting with 'A', you can't use `LIKE %A%`. The `%` will match everything in that "direction".

So, if you use `A%`, will match everything that starts with "A". If you use `%A` will match everything that ends with "A".